# ZIP Fit Indices Calculated from an EM Algorithm

Tags: expectation-maximization, lme4-nlme, zero-inflation, bic

I am working through @ben-bolker's owls example available here:https://groups.nceas.ucsb.edu/non-linear-modeling/projects/owls/WRITEUP/owls.pdf

In particular, I am making use of the R `zipme` function which is defined separately as follows:

```
zipme <- function(cformula, zformula, cfamily=poisson,
                  data, maxitr=20, tol=1e-6, verbose=TRUE) {
  #####################################
  ## EM algorithm for fitting ZIP mixed-effects model
  ##
  ##   y is the observation from the distribution:
  ##           P(Y=0)=p+(1-p)F(0,lambda)
  ##           P(Y=k)=(1-p)F(k,lambda).
  ##
  ##   data : the owl data frame with covariates; assumes data
  ## already pre-processed per pg 333 of Zuur et al 2009;
  ##        column order/names: Nest, FoodTreatment, SexParent, ArrivalTime,## NCalls, BroodSize, NegPerChick,
  ##        logbrdsze; logbrdsze is log(BroodSize).
  ##
  ##   formlog : formula for logistic regression. left side should be: z~
  ##   formpoi : formula for Poisson or NB regression. left side should be: y~
  ##
  ##   maxitr  : maximum number of iterations
  ##
  ## 2011.3.14 modified from Mihoko's GAMZINB to run ZIP mixed-effect model
  ##
  #############
  # number of observations
  m<-nrow(data)
  rname <- as.character(cformula)[2]

  ## initialize z and probz (z=1 -> perfect state; probz is probability of 0 in imperfect state for poisson)

  z<-numeric(m)
  probz<-numeric(m)
  z[data[[rname]]==0]<- 1/(1+exp(-1))  ## starting value

  ## n.b. we are looking for [3] since zformula has a LHS
  randz <- length(grep("\\(.*\\|.*\\)",as.character(zformula)[3]))>0
  ## delta is used to gauge convergence. after initialization, it is the abs. difference between current z and new z.    
  itr <- 1
  delta <- 2
  deltainfo <- numeric(maxitr)
  while(delta>tol & itr <= maxitr){
    if (verbose) cat("itr:",itr,"\n")
    ## make (update) working data frame
    bydataw <- data.frame(z=z,data)
    ##
    ## Maximization 1: logistic
    old.z<-z
    if (randz) {
      uu <- glmer(zformula, family=binomial, data=bydataw)
    } else {
      ## suppress warnings 
      uu <- suppressWarnings(glm(zformula, family=binomial, data=bydataw))
    }
    ## save current logistic model output
    u <- fitted(uu)
    ##
    ## Maximization 2: poisson loglinear with weights
    vv <- glmer(cformula, family=cfamily, weights=(1-z), data=bydataw)   
    ## save Poisson model output
    v <- fitted(vv)
    ##
    ## Expectation: used to update z with conditional expectation;only need to update at y=0.
    zdat <- data[[rname]]==0
    z[zdat] <- u[zdat]/( u[zdat]+(1-u[zdat])*exp(-v[zdat]))
    new.z<-z
    ## updated convergence indicator
    delta<-max(abs(old.z-new.z))
    ## save delta for this iteration; to be output
    deltainfo[itr] <- delta
    itr <- itr+1
  }            
  L <- list("zfit"=uu, "cfit"=vv, itr=itr, deltainfo=deltainfo, z=z)
  ##    uu.binom : output object of logistic regression; 
  ##    vv.flm   : output object of poisson regression
  class(L) <- "zipme"
  L
}
```

In essence, the function is an EM wrapper for fitting a ZIP mixed-effects model. The output of the function is, among other elements related to the maximization, two model objects - a mixed or fixed effect binomial GLM (for the zero component of the ZIP model) and a mixed or random effect Poisson GLM (for the Poisson component).

I would like to compare the output of `zipme` (`m2` below) to other models of the same data - a regular Poisson in particular (`m1` below).

For example, using Bolker's Owls data...

```
library(lme4)
download.file("https://groups.nceas.ucsb.edu/non-linear-modeling/projects/owls/DATA/Owls.rda", destfile = "Owls.rda")
load("Owls.rda")

Owls$NCalls <- Owls$SiblingNegotiation


Owls <- transform(Owls,ArrivalTime=scale(ArrivalTime,center=TRUE,scale=FALSE))


m1 <- glmer(NCalls~(FoodTreatment+ArrivalTime)*SexParent+
              offset(logBroodSize)+(1|Nest), family = "poisson", data=Owls)

m2 <- zipme(cformula=NCalls~(FoodTreatment+ArrivalTime)*SexParent+
        offset(logBroodSize)+(1|Nest),
      zformula=z ~ 1,
      data=Owls,maxitr=20,tol=1e-6,
      verbose=FALSE)

BIC(m1)
##[1] 5040.163

BIC(m2$cfit)
##[1] 3373.52
```

**Question: Is it ok for me to compare the output of `BIC(m1)` with the output of `BIC(m2$cfit)` *or* should I be calculating a summary fit index which includes both the binomial and Poisson components to compare back to `m1`?**

Comment: quick comment: I *think* you need BIC based on both parts of the model.  It would probably be best to start from scratch and calculate the likelihood and number of parameters yourself and put them together ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @gregor and @ben-bolker for getting me thinking along the following lines (@gregor via email and @ben-bolker above).

@ben-bolker noted that I should start from scratch with my own likelihood and @gregor noted

> My instinct is that adding the BIC's from each model component together sounds pretty good - and pretty easy. ZI model equations (and I think likelihoods) are two models multiplied together, so added together when logged... with correlations it might not be exactly that but seems like an acceptable estimate.

Thinking about this more, I think that this is not only an acceptable estimate, but indeed the correct method for calculating BIC.

Recall that the ZIP predicts $Y_i$ as

$$
Y_i=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
 0 \text{ with probability } \pi_i + (1 - \pi_i) e^{-\lambda_i} \\
 h \text{ with probability } (1 - \pi_i) \frac{\lambda^h_i e^{-\lambda_i}} {h_i!}.
                 \end{array}
              \right.
$$

The likelihood for this model is thus set up in two separate components:

$$
\begin{align}
 \mathcal{L_1} &= \prod_{y_i=0} \pi_i + (1 - \pi_i) e^{-\lambda_i},\qquad y_i = 0 \\
 \mathcal{L_2} &= \prod_{y_i>0} (1 - \pi) \frac{\lambda_i^{y_i} e^{-\lambda_i}} {y_i!},\qquad y_i \ge 1. 
\end{align}
$$

The total log-likelihood, $\ln\mathcal{L_T}$, is then simply given as

$$
\ln\mathcal{L_T} = \ln\mathcal{L_1} + \ln\mathcal{L_2}.
$$

Returning to BIC, we have the formula

$$
 \mathrm{BIC} = {-2 \cdot \ln{\mathcal{L_T}} + k \cdot \ln(n)}
$$

where $k$ is the number of estimated parameters and $n$ is the number of observations in our model.

We can thus calculate the BIC for a ZIP, as

$$
\begin{align}
 \mathrm{BIC_{ZIP}} &= {-2 \cdot \ln{\mathcal{L_T}} + (k_1 + k_2) \cdot \ln(n)} \\
&= (-2 \cdot \ln\mathcal{L_1} + (k_1) \cdot \ln(n)) + (-2 \cdot \ln\mathcal{L_2} + (k_2) \cdot \ln(n)) \\
&= BIC_1 + BIC_2
\end{align}
$$

where the subscripts $1$ and $2$ continue to indicate information from the Binomial and Poisson components of the ZIP respectively.

Unless I'm missing something, it appears to me that $gregor's intuition is correct.